# why don't the coordinates increment in this loop?

Tags: python

Got this loop where digits are loaded from a '.txt' attempting to make a grid of tiles for collision and for some reason even though counter1 and counter2 are incremented, every single unit is giving the same exact x and y coordinates. Here's the source code:

```
counter1 = 0
counter2 = 0
string = ''
with open('map.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for character in line:
            if character == '0':
                pass
            elif character == '1':
                environmentVector.append(environment.environment1)
                environmentVector[-1].x = counter1 * 32
                environmentVector[-1].y = counter2 * 32
            counter1 += 1
        counter1 = 0
        counter2 += 1
```

Comment: Hard to test without knowing what `environment.environment1` is but I would bet that it is a mutable type which means that you are appending the same object multiple times to your vector and so when you edit the x and y you're editing it for all entries.

Comment: you were right i fixed the problem

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you are appending the same object multiple times to your vector. Look at the following example

```
base_list = []

test_list = []

for i in range(0,5):
    base_list.append(test_list)
    base_list[-1].append(i)

print(base_list)
```

You might expect an output of

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

but you will actually get

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

because you are adding the same list every time to the base_list so editing it in one place in base_list will edit it in all of them.

The solution is to create a new `environment.environment1` object each time. I can't tell you how to do that without knowing what that class is, but in the example above, you would do;

```
for i in range(0,5):
    base_list.append(list())
    base_list[-1].append(i)
```